check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `activity_location`
When I tried to import the database structure from MySQL 8.0.34 to MySQL 8.0.30, shows error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `activity_location` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMEN' at line 35

this is the table create sql from 8.0.34:
/******************************************/
/*   DatabaseName = youzi   */
/*   TableName = activity_location   */
/******************************************/
CREATE TABLE `activity_location` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id',
  `biz_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'biz id',
  `biz_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `latitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000' COMMENT '',
  `longitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.000000' COMMENT '',
  `location` point DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `create_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  `update_time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  `deleted` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `tenant_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_biz_id` (`biz_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx_tenant_createtime` (`tenant_id`,`create_time`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='';

where am I missing something? BTW, I am running this script in DBeaver 21.2.4.

I pasted your statement at: https://dbfiddle.uk/UwbN7ZC3 and it seems ok. FWIW, I avoid quoted identifiers (like `activity_location`) unless I really need them.

Does the shown code is the only code placed into the DBeaver's window? and no chars before/after?

@Lennart-SlavaUkraini - I ran it also - no problemo! Gott nytt år!

I execute this script with seperate window and it works, but did not work work in single window.

@Vérace, Athbhliain faoi mhaise

The question you should ask is: "Does it run in the mysql CLI?"! If it does run in psql, then the problem lies with DBeaver. Maybe you could try removing parts of the last line and see what happens? Remove the COMMENTs?
